# Can't install numpy after a pip upgrade

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pip

For some reason, after pip is upgraded to version 19.0, I'm not able to install the most recent version of numpy (it still perfectly works with pip version 18.1).

When I run

```
pip install numpy --no-cache
```

I get this exception

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/.venvs/_/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 176, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/me/.venvs/_/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 346, in run
    session=session, autobuilding=True
  File "/home/me/.venvs/_/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/wheel.py", line 848, in build
    assert building_is_possible
AssertionError
```

I'm also using python version 3.6, and virtualenvwrapper version 16.0.0.

**UPD 0**

```
pip install numpy --no-cache -v
```

gives [this tremendous output](https://github.com/montreal91/stackoverflow-tracebacks/blob/master/pip19.out.log)

**UPD 1**
I've opened a [bug request](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/12833) on the numpy issue tracker.

Comment: Also pass ***-v*** (verbose) arg to *pip*, to get more output.

Comment: @CristiFati, updated the question

Comment: Try downloading the wheel file of numpy and installing from that, there also use the -v flag if it fails.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is because `pip v19.0` was released [yesterday](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/) and the latest push to the `numpy` [git rep](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/tree/v1.16.0) was 10 days ago. I think we have to wait for an update to be compatible with `pip v19.0`.

Edit 1:
Based on *@frmdstryr* comment, pip v19.0.1 has been released to fix this.

Comment: Should I issue a bugreport?

Comment: Yes you can. From the error message it is clear that numpy fails the `build_is_possible` assertion in `wheel.py` so it is a bug.

Comment: Pip 19.0.1 was just released to fix this