# I am trying to install packages (Numpy) in Pycharm get pip error

Tags: python, numpy, pip, pycharm

I am new to python and trying to install Numpy package in pycharm but I get an error in return please help me solve this problem I have uploaded a picture of this error.
I attempted to install pip within pycharm interpreter still no luck!

[Failed to install NumPy Package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSFRD.jpg)

Comment: It seems its an internet connection, make sure your pycharm proxy is the same as what you set for your bowser.

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981703/pip-install-fails-with-connection-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certi it seems that your Python installation is unable to use SSL due to missing packages and for that reason the package is not being installed.

Comment: Did you try `pip install ssl` ?

Comment: cannot install ssl- get same error

Answer (score 0):

This is because of a mismatch between your version of `pip` and `numpy`. See [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54326597/cant-install-numpy-after-a-pip-upgrade/54327300#54327300). Thus, first you must upgrade your `pip`:

On Linux or macOS:

```
pip install -U pip
```

On Windows:

```
python -m pip install -U pip
```

Once `pip` is updated, you may install `numpy`.